# Why are fonts of the same size displayed with different heights in different programs?

Tags: user-interface, fonts

I am currently working on a GUI at a Windows 7 64-bit PC. While comparing the visualisation of text in different programs, I recognized, that there are differences in how big text is displayed on my monitor, given the same text style and size.

Does anyone has an idea where this comes from?

I created this behaviour by typing a text in Arial Regular 12pt containing the letter `T` in a program and scaling the view to 100%. Afterwards I measured the height of the letter `T` in pixels with the help of a screenshot.

Programs I testet:

- MS Word 2010: `T` is 12 pixels high
- LibreOffice Writer 5.2.7.2 (x64): `T` is 12 pixels high
- Scribus 1.4.6: `T` is 12 pixels high
- GIMP 2.8.14: `T` is 9 pixels high
- Java 8 Update 181 (which I use for my own GUI): `T` is 9 pixels high

Answer (score 0):

pt (point) is a unit for physical sizes, typically 1/72th of an inch.

In order to transfer this to a size in pixels, you need to know how many pixels will be in one inch on your screen. This value is known as Pixels Per Inch (PPI), sometimes somewhat ambiguously called Dots Per Inch (DPI).

Note that this value will usually be different for an application UI and the documents you are working on.

From the values you provided, it looks like MS Word, LibreOffice and Scribus assume 72 PPI (or at least the documents you are working on do), whereas GIMP and Java use 96 PPI.

It's not obvious whether you are referring to the size of text ion the respective applications' UI or documents opened in them, though, so I could be totally off.